# Push Notification not showing Thumbnail Image

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am using Notification Service and Notification Content extensions to modify the notification. But in my notification, the content icon or the thumbnail image is not showing. But the content are appearing fine and working .

My Code :

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
        
        if let urlImageString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["urlImageString"] as? String {
            if let imageUrl = URL(string: urlImageString){
                
                downloadImage(from: imageUrl) { result in
                    switch result {
                            case .success(let localURL):
                                print("--->>> Image downloaded and saved at: \(localURL)")
                                do{
                                    let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "thumbnail", url: localURL, options: nil)
                                    bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print("--->>> Image download error: \(error)")
                            }
                }
            }
        }
        
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

func downloadImage(from imageURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "ImageDownloadError", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        do {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentsURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let imageFileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(imageURL.lastPathComponent)
            
            try data.write(to: imageFileURL)
            completion(.success(imageFileURL))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Do I need to maintain any other procedure? Or which procedure I am missing?